# pandas groupby two columns and fill the value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to firstly groupby the product and Code column and then fill the suppliers column with the first non null value

I was asking chatGPT but it cannot provide a solution.

the code looks like following:

```
# load the Pandas library
import pandas as pd


# create a dataframe with sample data
test = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple','apple','banana', 'banana', 'orange', 'orange','orange'],
                     'Code':[1,2,1,1,3,3,4,5,4],
                   'supplier': [None, None,None, 'Acme Inc.', 'Cotsco ', None, None, 'Target', None],
                   'quantity': [99,58,100, 200, 150, 50, 300, 20,400]})

# group the dataframe by the 'product' and 'Code' columns
test_grouped = test.groupby(['product', 'Code'])

# get the first non-null value in the 'supplier' column for each group
suppliers = test_grouped['supplier'].first()

# fill missing values in the 'supplier' column for each group using the first non-null value
test = test_grouped.apply(lambda x: x.assign(supplier=x['supplier'].fillna(suppliers[x.name])))

# print the updated dataframe
print(test)
```

the code errored with:

```
ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.
```

Comment: What is the expected output on the given input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size by original DataFrame and pass to [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
test_grouped = test.groupby(['product', 'Code'])
test['supplier'] = test['supplier'].fillna(test_grouped['supplier'].transform('first'))
print (test)
  product  Code   supplier  quantity
0   apple     1  Acme Inc.        99
1   apple     2       None        58
2   apple     1  Acme Inc.       100
3   apple     1  Acme Inc.       200
4  banana     3    Cotsco        150
5  banana     3    Cotsco         50
6  orange     4       None       300
7  orange     5     Target        20
8  orange     4       None       400
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted